# Promise does not wait for timeout

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am learning Promise library but stuck on the following problem.

```
//Function for getting sum
    function getSum(n1, n2) {   
       var isAnyNegative = function() {   
          return n1 < 0 || n2 < 0;   
       }
       var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {   
          if (isAnyNegative()) {   
             reject(Error("Negatives not supported"));   
          }   
          resolve(n1 + n2)
       });   
       return promise;   
    }

 ////Function for getting Difference
    function getDiff(n1,n2){
        var diff = n1-n2;
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("value of diff--- ", diff)
            return diff;
        }, 2000)
    }

    getSum(5,6)
    .then(function(callbackResult){
        console.log("first callback-Result- ", callbackResult)
        return getDiff(14,11);
    }, function(error){
        //handling error
    })
    .then(function(callbackResult){
        console.log("second callback--Result- ", callbackResult)
        return getSum(22,22);
    }, 
    function(error){
        //handling error
    })
    .then(function(callbackResult){
        console.log("third callback--Result- ", callbackResult)
    }, function(error){
        //handling error
    })
```

The output I am getting for this code snippet:-

```
first callback-Result-  11
second callback--Result-  undefined
third callback--Result-  44
value of diff---  3
```

Why doesn't second callback wait for the difference function to return. I think this is the main feature of Promise library to Synchronize the code.

Comment: Yes it kinda is. But setTimeout is an async call aswell

Comment: Look at @GrégoryNEUT's answer. In fact when you return in the timeout, you don't return in the diff function. The same applies for, for instance, `map` method.
    `function x(){
        array.map(function(el){return el});
    }`
When calling `x()` it will not return the first element in the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You gotta deal with `setTimeout` in an asynchronous way. For example :

```
function getDiff(n1,n2){
   return new Promise((resolve) => {
        const diff = n1 - n2;

        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log('value of diff--- ', diff);

            return resolve(diff);
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Another option if you're using the [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.delay.html) library is to use `Bluebird.delay(2000)`, which waits 2 seconds and then resolves the returned promise.

Comment: @Griffin yes you can do that, but why use `Bluebird` when `node.js` do supports natively `Promises` now ?

Comment: Definitely a good point, es6 is getting a lot of new stuff. There are really 2 reasons I like to use things like Bluebird and lodash, even though native JavaScript supports them:
1. Even though you can control the server's environment and node version, you can't control what browsers people visit your website on, so if you have frontend code that uses these features, even Safari sometimes doesn't support them. These libraries can polyfill for you so you don't have to worry about it.
2. The utility functions libraries like these save me typing, and it's easy to understand what they're doing.

Comment: @Griffin theses are valid point :). Just saying you can also use [Babel transpiler](https://babeljs.io/) to handle the browser compatibility struggle. Both works, i guess this is more depending about the existing architecture you have.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are returning **diff** in an anonymous function inside timeout. If you want to wait promise chain, you must return Promise instance from **getDiff**, like you did it earlier in **getSum**.

```
function getDiff(n1,n2){
    var diff = n1-n2;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            console.log("value of diff--- ", diff)
            resolve(diff);
        }, 2000);
    });
}
```