# JS: Expected behavior from Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I am finally coming to accepting to use Promises instead of callbacks.  I have a question though. Doesn't a promise return a promise?  If I run this: `promise.then(one).then(two)` based off the functions below, should I expect that `two` doesn't fire until `one` is complete?  In my console,
I see 'TWO' logged, then 'ONE' logged 4 seconds later.

```
promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
     resolve("!!")
  }, 3000);
});

function one() {
    setTimeout(() => {
       console.log("ONE")
    }, 4000);
}

function two() {
    console.log("TWO")
}
```

Comment: `setTimeout` does not return a promise, you can make it return a promise by writing it like your first `Promise` constructor

Comment: Watch this [Broken Promises by James Snell](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=XV-u_Ow47s0)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Promise does not wait for timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404912/promise-does-not-wait-for-timeout)

Comment: @AmareshSM yes this does!  Sorry I didn't find this in my search before posting

Comment: Thanks @iSkore , watching this now

Comment: Ya, because setTimeout is scheduling an async event, it’s not going to run on first pass of execution. The next block of code is executed then asynchronous events are completed after because the first pass of execution puts a “reference” to them on the event loop and moves on. Once that’s all complete, the async method are gathered and ran. This happens because async events are sort of like to “mid priority threads” - if a task is urgent/immediate priority, it would be a blocking synchronous task on the main thread

Comment: No problem! That should cover every major aspect of async/await and promises for you. It’s a great watch for anyone new **and** experienced with promises!

Answer (score 0):

> should I expect that `two` doesn't fire until `one` is complete

Yes you're right, `one` must be completed before `two` started to run. But *complete* what, what does it mean by *complete*? In your function `one`, *complete* means `setTimeout`, or **set a task running `console.log("ONE")` in 4 seconds**, not **waiting for 4 seconds and run `console.log("ONE")`**, that's what `setTimeout` means.

So *as you should expect*, after `one` completed **setting the task** to run `console.log("ONE")` *(what `one()` does is to set the task to log, not log)*, then `two` fires, which runs `console.log("TWO")`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, essentially the callback function `one` is getting called first and `two` is getting called after it.

You're just getting a feeling that `two` got called first because you saw `TWO` on the console first.

If you place a `console.log` in both these methods, you'll see the ACTUAL sequence.

Give this a try:

```js
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve("!!")
  }, 3000);
});

function one(returnValue) {
  console.log('returnValue from 1', returnValue);
  return setTimeout(() => {
    console.log("ONE")
  }, 4000);
}

function two(returnValue) {
  console.log('returnValue from 2', returnValue);
  console.log("TWO")
}

promise.then(one).then(two);
```

Once the method `one` has returned, the method `two` would get called. Method `one` would return the `setTimeout` almost instantly. And then `two` would get called which would then log `TWO` to the console. And then after the 4 sec, delay the callback function inside `setTimeout` in method `one` would get called that would then print `ONE` on the console, giving you an impression that `two` got called first.

Does the explanation make sense?